# Change Folder permissions

Tags: file, permissions, batch-file, directory

Well my question is somewhat complicated
I hope I can ask it right
I rack my brain for over a month
I try to change permissions of a folder using the command line (Windows) the situation is like so
the Username should be like the folder name (users already exist)
That means if the folder is called Davidy So the user theat has  full control over it will be Davidy
I have over 200 such folders so you can understand why I want to do this using a script
The problem is that I do not know how to tell the script to use the name of the folder as THE username.

Comment: I have no idea what your question is?

Comment: I would like to know how to use the name of the folder as a variable in a script
So I can use the folder name inside the script
Example
`takeown /u domainname\%foldername% c:\folder`
How do I do this?

Comment: So you have all users and folders created, you just now need to iterate over the usernames, and assign their corresponding folders full permissions to them? Also, what is the full path to these user folders?

Comment: Yes That's it.  The folders are located on a DFS in the same folder in the NameSpace

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute the following command in the folder that contains all your folders:

`` FOR /F "useback" %i in (`dir /ad /b`) DO  mycommand ``

you should end up having the folder name in `%i`. If you are executing this command inside a batch file, make sure you use `%%i` instead of `%i`.

Based on the command you posted in your comment, it would look like this:

`` FOR /F "useback" %i in (`dir /ad /b`) DO takeown /u domainname\% .\%i ``

Comment: First off all thanks for answering :) i will chack this script first thing on the morning. By the way if a situation occurs where there is no user that matches the name of the folder How can I set the script to skip over it Instead of closing the loop (What I can guess will happen in this kind of situation)?

Comment: I don't think the loop will stop, I would expect it to continue, even if an error occurs.

Comment: Well its not working Because I'm trying to give a domain user permission so it Forcing me to use another switch (/s)
and I dont know how to combine it